# Binding keys in Emacs when Evil-mode is not used

Tags: emacs

I want to retain all Emacs original key binding in Evil insert mode, but I want to rebind some of them for cases when evil-mode is not enabled for some reason (in specific buffers). For example, I want to map `M-q` to `save-buffers-kill-terminal` to only work in all modes except Evil-insert-mode where is should do what the original Emacs key binding does (`fill-paragraph`). How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make `M-q` execute `save-buffers-kill-terminal` by default, you will want to change `M-q`'s global keybinding:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-q") 'save-buffers-kill-terminal)
```

But, remember, global keybindings are overridden by mode-specific bindings. In fact, we are going to take advantage of this:

To make a special exception for `M-q` in Evil-mode when inserting, add a specific keybinding for `fill-paragraph` into evil-insert-state's keybinding "map":

```
(define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "M-q") 'fill-paragraph)
```

This one will override the global binding, and will only work in Evil-mode's insert state.

Adding those two lines to your .emacs configuration file should do the trick.